# How to append string value in Shared Preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have made a test activity that stores your marks in shared preferences and then I want those marks to be shown in another activity as a list, Being a newbie I think I have to append the initial score value into another shared preference and even after days of trying I am unable to get it done.

I have already seen similar questions asked on the site and none of them gave me exactly what I want. What do I need to do in that case? Please provide a snippet of code to guide me through.

Comment: So you want to save a list of Strings? There are multiple options, like using a proper (sql) database or converting your list to a json string representative, save that then when retrieving convert it back to a list

Answer (score 0):

Using Gson for saving Result value in key and object without append string.

put gson Gradle file in Gradle. main
**implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'**

Save Result in SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(myObject); 
prefsEditor.putString("Key", "Value");
prefsEditor.commit();
```

get value from SharedPreferences:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = mPrefs.getString("Key", "");
MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class);
```

Download Github code [FromHere](https://github.com/pchauhan/StoreandRetrieveObjectClassDemo)